# Casting Giant Form 2 and choosing Giant form 1 size, which size bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

When you cast [Giant form 1](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i) you gain +6 size bonus to str and become large. Giant form 2 adds huge forms to the ones you can select but also keeps the large ones. So if I use giant form 2 and choose a large form, because I used the 2 spell and not the first, despite being the same as GF1, do I get +6 or +8 str?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cast Giant Form 2 you have the **option** to select form several sizes (from large to huge) but it clearly states:

> You gain the following abilities:
>
> - +8 size bonus to Strength
> - -2 penalty to Dexterity
> - +6 size bonus to Constitution
> - +6 natural armor bonus
> - low-light vision
> - +10 foot enhancement bonus to your speed

So you don´t have option to choose your STR bonus, only the size according to the creature you choose.

Font:
[Giant Form](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i)

Comment: I was just checking to see if the new size modifiers in GF2 still overwrote the ones for the forms in GF1. I was fairly sure that was the case but not positive.

Comment: @Fering Next time it would be useful to put these notes explaining your questions into your questions when first writing them.

Comment: I thought it was...sorry about that then